# Obtener datos de usuario logueado y mostrarlos en C# usando php y Json

Tags: php, javascript, c#, json, serialización

Quiero obtener los datos de el usuario logueado (username, email, plan...) que estar guardados en una db.

```html
<?php
include 'db_conn.php';

$action = (isset($_POST['act'])) ? $_POST['act'] : '0';
$username = (isset($_POST['username'])) ? $_POST['username'] : '0';
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : '0';



if($action === "qwjFpPXuGexZBHDJEreZrAUH"){

  if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
    $username = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $username);
    $password = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $password);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

                if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
                  $d = array('CODE' => '500');
                  echo json_encode($d);
                  $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
                  $res = $conn->query($sql);
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                  $id = $row->id;
                  $arr = array('id' => $row->id, 'Information' => $row);
                  echo json_encode($arr);
                }               
                }else{
                    if($result->num_rows === 0){
                    $d = array('CODE' => '402');
                    echo json_encode($d);
                  }else{
                        $d = array('CODE' => '6');
                        echo json_encode($d);
                  }
                  }
  }
}
```

No estoy seguro si estoy haciendo la peticion correcta para la serializacion. La info que quiero enviar debe coincidir con el usuario logueado obviamente para luego poder deserializarla en c#. Tengo esta clase creada que es donde quiero recibir la info del json.

```
public class Information
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public string activationdate { get; set; }
    public string terminationdate { get; set; }

    public Information()
    {
    }
```

y tengo esta otra que se encarga de procesar el login:

```
internal class SECURITY_ACCOUNT
{
    public SECURITY_ACCOUNT()
    {
    }

    public static async Task Login(string Username, string Password)
    {
        string str = "https://url/log.php";
        string[] cID = new string[] { "act=qwjFpPXuGexZBHDJEreZrAUH&CID=", "&username=", Username, "&password=", Password };
        string str1 = string.Concat(cID);
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Proxy = null;
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string str2 = webClient.UploadString(str, str1).Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Trim();
            ACC.RESP = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RESPONSE>(str2);
            if (ACC.RESP.CODE == "500")
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
                
                Vulcan._Login.Hide();
                Vulcan._form1.Show();
                
            }
            else if (ACC.RESP.CODE == "402")
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Username / Password Incorrect");
            }
            else if (ACC.RESP.CODE == "6")
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You cannot log in because your account is linked to another computer");
            }
            
        }
    }
```

El login funciona bien pero los label que tengo en el dashboard no muestran nada:

```
public void getdata() 
    {
        label11.Text = ACC.DATA.Information.username;
```

}

Mi logica (que obviamente no es correcta) es que a traves de $arr = array('id' => $row->id, 'Information' => $row);
echo json_encode($arr); tome lo que necesito y lo almacene en la clase Information para que luego pueda mostrar lo que esta dentro de la clase en labels en el dashboard. Que estoy haciendo mal y como puedo solucionarlo? Cualquier ayuda es valiosa.